# Lorem ipsum generator tag in Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I provided an answer today where it would be helpful to fill up my Demo snippet with a bunch of paragraphs of dummy text. The page contents affects the behaviour of the demo and this can be illustrated easily in a snippet.

This happens every now and then, **but I don't always add text as it would result in a lot of noise in the snippet.**

This got me thinking - wouldn't it be neat to generate dummy paragraphs of text **that aren't shown in the code snippet?** It could look something like this:

```
<div id="content"><!-- lorem-ipsum: 5 --></div>
```

Voila! 5 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum inside my content div when the snippet is rendered, please. Looks better than this snippet below; the text is noisy and makes the markup harder to read.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header></header>
        <div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rutrum leo turpis, non aliquet mi vulputate ac. Phasellus vitae luctus urna, eu condimentum urna. Maecenas placerat velit dui, vitae tristique elit porta id. Sed vel vehicula odio, non luctus nisl. Curabitur at viverra magna. In vehicula cursus vestibulum. In mollis aliquam pellentesque. Etiam sed accumsan sapien. Vivamus finibus mattis faucibus. Nam maximus molestie diam eu venenatis. Duis urna sem, ultricies vitae tempor nec, dignissim ac risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis viverra ultrices ligula, in mattis est luctus ac. Phasellus turpis libero, ullamcorper eget justo in, venenatis luctus quam. In nec ipsum vel elit suscipit eleifend. Pellentesque in arcu efficitur, lacinia mi a, sagittis ipsum.</p>

<p>Vivamus bibendum tincidunt leo in malesuada. Sed interdum viverra odio vitae lacinia. Etiam eros risus, pharetra quis nulla vel, finibus sodales lacus. Nulla hendrerit eros leo, vel congue enim pulvinar eget. Duis quis metus sed purus rhoncus luctus sit amet id arcu. Nulla facilisi. Proin varius sit amet nisi ut molestie. Nunc imperdiet lacus sed varius bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus eleifend tempor lorem id ullamcorper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam consequat viverra ligula molestie tincidunt. Donec id lectus venenatis, ultrices purus eget, mollis nunc. Ut lacinia leo non augue egestas mattis sit amet at tortor. Donec luctus mi ut magna faucibus molestie.</p>

<p>Mauris placerat malesuada sem a blandit. Nulla sed orci nibh. Vestibulum mi felis, euismod sed facilisis sed, viverra et metus. Donec malesuada malesuada magna, at aliquet nibh hendrerit vitae. Fusce tempus dui metus, vitae vehicula mauris lobortis at. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus pretium rutrum sem auctor placerat. Sed dictum leo sed molestie facilisis. Morbi convallis nibh nec egestas sagittis. Aliquam non nisi vitae nisi rhoncus rhoncus. Nullam venenatis nibh et fermentum dignissim. Sed rhoncus arcu leo, quis malesuada lectus scelerisque vel.</p>

<p>Donec sagittis odio quis ipsum dictum, tempus tempor diam luctus. Aenean sodales risus at sem sollicitudin, eget elementum erat aliquam. Cras dictum aliquet justo sit amet congue. Aenean tristique dictum interdum. Nunc condimentum at mauris in fringilla. Curabitur non convallis quam, et bibendum libero. Maecenas vitae eros vel orci mattis hendrerit. Vivamus in lobortis felis. Vestibulum auctor metus sed arcu pharetra molestie. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer vel nulla eros. Suspendisse placerat ultrices convallis. Nam dictum laoreet purus, a posuere libero imperdiet in.</p>

<p>Vivamus dictum ac odio eu suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc ac fringilla odio. Ut molestie, ante vitae tincidunt scelerisque, metus quam aliquam lectus, eget sollicitudin turpis urna sed nulla. Nulla nec metus nec ligula fermentum rhoncus. Mauris vel malesuada quam, quis bibendum magna. Nulla luctus elementum ligula non ultrices. Vivamus aliquet nibh id rutrum tincidunt. Fusce rutrum, magna eu posuere vestibulum, dui ex ornare risus, ut malesuada augue leo eget augue. Pellentesque ut ipsum id justo malesuada interdum. Suspendisse scelerisque pellentesque erat, et interdum ex efficitur vitae. Duis sed lacinia libero. Sed magna libero, iaculis at tempor non, malesuada vel lacus. Vivamus bibendum placerat dolor, ut aliquet elit ornare vitae. Quisque turpis urna, tincidunt non placerat ac, tincidunt nec urna.</p>
        </div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: That was an embarrassing typo!

Comment: You have to install the Lorem Ipsum dictionary to catch that one. Few people have it installed.

Comment: Jeff Atwood put together a great list of [lorem ipsum generators](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-eternal-lorem-ipsum/), I usually use [this one](http://www.zombieipsum.com/).